# CakePHP 2.x not producing json response

Tags: php, json, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a Cake 2.x application. I need to provide a JSON encoded response from a PHP array, but it's not working as expected.

In `app/Config/routes.php` I have `Router::parseExtensions('json');`

In my Controller I have this code:

```
public function ajaxTags()
{
    $this->loadModel('Tag');
    $tags = $this->Tag->find('list');
    var_dump($tags);
    die;
}
```

This produces what I expect - a PHP array of data in my `'tags'` database table, e.g.

```
array(4) { 
    [1]=> string(14) "United Kingdom"
    [2]=> string(6) "France"
    [3]=> string(7) ... 
}
```

So all I want to do is get this as JSON encoded data. I've followed the instructions at https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html

So at the top of my `TagsController.php` I have:

```
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

And then I try and output it using `_serialize` as stated in the docs. I don't need a "view" for this because I don't want to do any additional formatting:

```
public function ajaxTags()
{
    $this->loadModel('Tag');
    $tags = $this->Tag->find('list');
    $this->set('_serialize', array($tags));
}
```

This gives the following response:

`null`

The response data is encoded as `Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8` (I can see this in my browser Network tab).

Where am I going wrong? I know that `$tags` has data in it because I `var_dump`'d it earlier. Why is it giving a null output now?

Comment: Try to put to replace `$this->set('_serialize', array($tags));` by `$this->set('tags', $tags); $this->set('_serialize', array('tags'));`

Comment: @SamHecquet yes, that works. But why? Thank you.

Comment: I edited my answer to explain why you need to set this variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html), your action should be like this:

```
public function ajaxTags()
{
    $this->loadModel('Tag');
    $tags = $this->Tag->find('list');
    $this->set('tags', $tags);
    $this->set('_serialize', array('tags'));
}
```

> The _serialize key is a special view variable that indicates which
>   other view variable(s) should be serialized when using a data view.

You need to send the variable `$tags` to the view so the `_serialize` key will know it and will render it.